# How to use Python to save nacl SigningKey public and private keys as plain text?

Tags: python, text, base64, nacl-cryptography, pynacl

I must be missing something in the [nacl docs](https://pynacl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signing/). How do I save both the private and public keys in plain text? The available encoders are Raw (binary?), Hex, Base16/32/64 and URLSafeBase64Encoder.

I thought I would just use the `base64` library to convert the Base64-encoded key.

**Example:**

```py
from nacl.signing import SigningKey
from nacl.encoding import Base64Encoder
from base64 import b64decode


# Create SigningKey as base64-encoded bytes

signing_key = SigningKey.generate().encode(encoder=Base64Encoder)
print(type(signing_key))


# Convert base64-encoded bytes to string

signing_key = signing_key.decode('utf-8')
print(type(signing_key))


# Decode base64 string to plain text

signing_key = b64decode(signing_key)
print(type(signing_key))
print(signing_key)
```

**Results:** Bytes object

```py
<class 'bytes'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'bytes'>
b'e\xfa ?H\xd8\xe7^2\xfa1\x18\xa61\xca\x95\xec~\x8c\x011[\xf8\x05q!\xfc\xe4\x94\x13\xc2\x89'
```

**Tried:**

- The [`Decoding Strings with Python`](https://stackabuse.com/encoding-and-decoding-base64-strings-in-python/) tutorial here, and all sorts of variations.
- None of them lead to the plain text version of the `SigningKey`
- I'm looking for the `-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----` etc. in plain text
- How do I force the `b64decode` function to show plain text?

Comment: I believe that "plain text" format you are referring to is called PEM format.  It is essentially base64 with those ----- BEGIN ----- headers and footers

Comment: Also, keep in mind that these keys, in raw format, are just a series of bytes that have no good text representation w/o an encoding (like base64 or hexidecimal).  That is, they wont mean very much being displayed in "raw" format. There will be several non-alphanumeric characters (even stuff like newlines)

Comment: Hm...the output from `signing_key = SigningKey.generate().encode(encoder=Base64Encoder)` seems to be only 32 chars long. Are both the private and public keys present in just this short result?

Comment: This is beyond my knowledge, but I believe that signing key is just the private key.  Using other crypto libs, usually a function like `SigningKey.generate()` will return an object that provides a method for obtaining a corresponding public key.  Meaning the public key is derived from the generated private key

Comment: Hm...I'm confused by the [examples here](https://github.com/pyca/pynacl/blob/main/docs/signing.rst#example-2). It sure looks like the result of `SigningKey.generate()` can be used to cryptographically sign a message https://github.com/pyca/pynacl/blob/main/docs/signing.rst#example-2. But as I read further down, it looks like `.generate()` is just a seed(?)

Comment: just left an answer, sorry it took a while to get back to your last comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly the same as the link you attached in your comment, but here is a more succinct example that may help

```py
signing_key = SigningKey.generate()

priv_key_b64 = signing_key.encode(encoder=Base64Encoder)
pub_key_b64  = signing_key.verify_key.encode(encoder=Base64Encoder)

data = b'testtest'

signed_b64 = signing_key.sign(data, encoder=Base64Encoder)

print(priv_key_b64)         # private key in alpha-numeric encoding
print(pub_key_b64)          # public key in alpha-numeric encoding
print(signed_b64)           # data & signature over data in single chunk

verified = signing_key.verify_key.verify(signed_b64, encoder=Base64Encoder)

print(verified)             # origin 'data' (testtest)
```

To respond to your comment about the seed, the `SigningKey.generate()` generates a random seed for you and uses that to construct a private (signing) key.  You could provide your own seed using `signing_key = SigningKey(seed, encoder=RawEncoder)`

Comment: Thank you, this helps. I'm used to seeing an RSA-type key where there are a lot more b64 characters in the space between `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` and `-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`. I was expecting to decode the b64 and see the public / private key in its entirety (BEG, b64, END).